# how can create table with last n records order by time desc - clickhouse

Tags: database, clickhouse

I have a table named tbl1 in the db database with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE db.tbl1 (
    col1 Int64,
    col2 Int64,
    col3 Int64,
    timestamp DateTime
) ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY (col1, timestamp);
```

My query

```
select col1,col2,col3
from db.tbl
where col1 in (1,2,3...)
order by timestamp desc 
limit 10000 by col1;
```

I want to create a new table or materialized view that stores the last 10000 records of tbl1 ordered by the timestamp column and deletes the old records. or if anyone can do it with TTL to delete the old records if the total count is more than 10000 How can I achieve this?
because my table has billions of records and my query takes more than 2 minutes.

Comment: What is not possible with using Clickhouse table  engines / or TTL.

Comment: how can i add a condition in TTL to delete the earliest record if the col1 has more than 10000 records? is there a way to do it ?

Comment: How fast are you inserting data? You could probably do something clever with a MV and TTL - maybe hang on to the last 5 minutes of rows or something like that

Comment: I am merging records in the ingestion layer, either until I have 20,000 of them or until 5 hours have passed, whichever comes first